# BoxDecoration widget missing padding property

Tags: flutter, dart

The [BoxDecoration class docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html) show that this widget has a `padding` property.

Yet when I use it with this property, I get that:
`The named parameter 'padding' isn't defined`.

I thought maybe my version of flutter was out of date, but I'm using v1.7.8+hotfix.4, which is the [most recent](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases) (as of August 7th 2019), so I'm not sure how to fix this error.

My code looks something like:

```
DrawerHeader(
  ...
  decoration: BoxDecoration(... padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0))
)
```

Comment: @pskink, that was helpful and it looks like padding is from border?.dimensions. If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: your welcome, feel free to write a self answer

Comment: This might look like you want to give background padding. 1. Add the above container in Stack.2. Keep the container with decoration in top of stack. 3. You might want to give margin to the container in top of stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @pskink mentioned in the comments, the `BoxDecoration` constructor doesn't have a `padding` parameter, so it's determined by `padding = border?.dimensions` instead.

Comment: A full example would help, especially since the link above no longer works.

Answer (score 2):

I saw that the answer above is incomplete, so here is my full example answer hope it helps.
`decoration: BoxDecoration()`  have padding property because it is a class property

```
DrawerHeader(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
          child: ...
),
```