# How to give padding for the scrollbar in the dropdown in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dropdown

```
import 'package:dropdown_button2/dropdown_button2.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';

class LocationDropdown extends StatefulWidget {
  final List cities;
  final String? selectedCity;
  final Color? locationIconColor;
  final Color? iconColor;
  final Color? textColor;
  final Function(String?) onLocationChange;
  final double? width;
  final Offset? offset;

  const LocationDropdown({
    Key? key,
    required this.cities,
    required this.selectedCity,
    this.locationIconColor,
    this.iconColor,
    this.textColor,
    this.width,
    this.offset,
    required this.onLocationChange,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LocationDropdown> createState() => _LocationDropdownState();
}

class _LocationDropdownState extends State<LocationDropdown> {
  bool isDropDownButtonClicked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
      child: DropdownButton2<String>(
        onMenuStateChange: (value) {
          setState(() {
            isDropDownButtonClicked = value;
          });
        },
        isExpanded: true,
        hint: Row(
          children: [
            SvgPicture.asset(
              Constants.marker,
              height: 16,
              color: widget.locationIconColor,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 5,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: widget.width == null ? null : (widget.width! - 40),
              child: Text(
                "${widget.selectedCity}",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14,
                  color: widget.textColor ?? Colors.white,
                ),
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                maxLines: 1,
              ),
            ),
            const Spacer(),
            RotatedBox(
              quarterTurns: isDropDownButtonClicked ? 2 : 0,
              child: SvgPicture.asset(
                Constants.downward_white_icon,
                width: 15,
                color: widget.iconColor,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        items: widget.cities
            .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: item,
                  child: Text(
                    "$item",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontWeight: "Mumbai" == item
                            ? FontWeight.w500
                            : FontWeight.w300,
                        color: widget.selectedCity == item
                            ? ColorCode.secondaryColor
                            : ColorCode.placeholderDefault),
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ))
            .toList(),
        onChanged: widget.onLocationChange,
        icon: const SizedBox.shrink(),
        buttonElevation: 2,
        itemHeight: 35,
        itemPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 14, right: 14),
        dropdownMaxHeight: 140,
        dropdownWidth: 150,
        dropdownPadding: null,
        dropdownDecoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primaryContainer,
        ),
        scrollbarRadius: const Radius.circular(40),
        scrollbarThickness: 2.w,
        scrollbarAlwaysShow: true,
        offset: widget.offset ?? const Offset(0, 0),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm using "DropdownButton2" package for creating the dropdown. I want to give top and right padding for the scrollbar . I'm not able to find any solutions. Please help.
Currently it looks like this

[image]

But it should look like this
[image]

Scrollbar should have padding to the top and right like this.

How to achieve padding to the scrollbar in this "dropdownbutton2" package. I searched for other packages as well but didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to latest version and use `dropdownScrollPadding` parameter.

dropdownPadding: The inner padding of the dropdown menu.

dropdownScrollPadding: The inner padding of the dropdown menu including the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

I may not be right but try in this part

```
  dropdownPadding: null,
  dropdownDecoration: BoxDecoration(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
  color: Colors.redAccent,
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, right: 10.0)
  ),
```

adding to `BoxDecoration` padding.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html

Comment: There is not padding property in the BoxDecoration class

Comment: @NithyashreeBL There is.

Comment: But in this package it is not there.

Comment: `dropdownDecoration`,

Comment: I added my answer what do I mean.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57404623/boxdecoration-widget-missing-padding-property

Comment: padding property isn't defined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248035/discussion-between-nithyashree-b-l-and-sonic).